# How exactly does this pattern work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$$3, 4.5, 5.25, 8.125$$

So supposedly this series of numbers actually share something in common but I'm sorta stuck on it. As far as I could figure out, the decimal places were $$\frac{1}{2^{i-1}}$$ but beyond that I was unable to figure out a way to correlate $3, 4, 5$ and $8$. Supposedly this number series requires nothing beyond pre-calc but maybe I'm overthinking something or going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n + 2^{-n}$

where $a_n$ is the $n$th integer that starts with $10$ in binary.

$a_0 = (10)_2 = 2, a_1=(100)_2=4, a_2=(101)_2=5, a_3=(1000)_2=8, a_4=(1001)_2=9,$ etc.

re: [OEIS A004754](https://oeis.org/A004754)

Answer (score 1):

If you index the terms so that $3$ is the $0$th term, then multiply the $i$th term by $2^i$ you have $$3, 9, 21, 65$$ This integer sequence only has [one hit on OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C+9%2C+21%2C+65&language=english&go=Search). And it's not sequence with a nice simple formula. But using this or some other formula $f(i)$  to produce $3, 9, 21, 65$, your numbers are $\frac{1}{2^i}f(i)$.